# How to leverage GoogleMap MarkerShape in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to leverage the GoogleMap Marker in React, but it seems the shape interface does not work.
Here's my code, the image shows correctly but not the shape, is there anything wrong?

```
        const myIcon = {
          url: './IMG_4033.JPG',
          scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(100, 100),
          anchor: { x: 100, y: 100 }
        };
        const marker_shape = {coords: [50, -50, 50], type: "circle"};
        return(<><Marker icon={myIcon} animation={window.google.maps.Animation.DROP} position={ lat: 46.97722, lng: -68.992028 } shape={marker_shape} /></>);
```

Any information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map
```

This one may be helpful for you brother